# Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:

Tags: java, json

I get this error:
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=java&type=post
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:19)

for this code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import javax.json.*;



public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          try {
              URL url = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=java&type=post");
              InputStream is = url.openStream();
              JsonReader rdr = Json.createReader(is);        
              JsonObject obj = rdr.readObject();
              JsonArray results = obj.getJsonArray("data");
              for (JsonObject result : results.getValuesAs(JsonObject.class)) {
                  System.out.print(result.getJsonObject("from").getString("name"));
                  System.out.print(": ");
                  System.out.println(result.getString("message", ""));
                  System.out.println("-----------");
              }
          } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and i don't understand why?

Comment: HTTP 400 means : The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.

Answer (score 0):

When simply trying that URL in the browser, I get response:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104,
      "fbtrace_id": "Du6VLoot53K"
   }
}
```

It also has a response code of 400, so that seems clear enough as to *why* you get it:
**An access token is required.**

I see nothing in your code trying to provide such an access token.